# Does a file that has been passed as a parameter to a function which processes it using the with statement in Python have to be closed explicitly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The `with` statement closes files automatically. However, in an online course there are instructions to close a file after processing it in the body of a `with` block which was also part of a function:

```
def write_report(dictionary, report_file):
    with open(report_file, "w+") as f:
        for k in sorted(dictionary):
            f.write(str(k)+":"+str(dictionary[k])+"\n")
        f.close()
```

To test whether the file had been left open, the code was temporarily modified to return `f.closed` which was `True` both with and without `f.close()`.

Is this force of habit or does it have something to do with passing the file as a parameter to the function? Could opening the file in read/write mode necessitate this?

Comment: You're saying that code is from a course? Can you link to that?

Comment: It's a paid course, here's the link: https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-operating-system (it's the graded assessment for week 2, the qwiklabs one)

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is the file name `report_file` is passed to the function. Not the file itself.

There is is **no need** to call `f.close()`. The file will be closed when exiting the `with` block.

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files